# UITextView Detect Line Breaks

Tags: textview, uitextview

I have a UITextView. I want to be able to detect every single line break and replace it with other content that can be decoded later. So, if there is

> Hey
>
> Tim

it would automatically encode it to something like:

> Hey%29Tim

Then, there would be another way to decode it back.

Is that possible? I know it is not that clear, but I don't understand how to explain it. So, if you have questions, ask below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text in a `UITextView` is just a `String` instance, where line breaks are represented by escape character `\n`. Hence, you could read the `.text` property of your `UITextView` instance and replace it with a string where you've replaced the escape character `\n` with whatever you like; in your case `%29`.

Example:

```
var myString = "Hey\nTim"
print(myString)
/* Hey
   Tim  */

myString = myString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "%29")
print(myString)
/* Hey%29Tim */
```

Comment: @OliverLeopold Happy to help!